# How to rename "wwwroot" folder used as web root in ASP.NET 5 web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I would like to rename the web root folder in my ASP.NET 5 project to something other than `wwwroot`. When I manually rename that folder, the project no longer recognizes it as the web root folder. The project properties page does not allow the web root to be modified. Is there any way to rename and/or reassign the web root folder in ASP.NET 5 web projects?

Comment: [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html?highlight=wwwroot%20project%20json#the-wwwroot-folder)

Comment: @vinjenzo Thanks, but the info in those docs is old and webroot is ignored in the project.json file.

Comment: thanks for your link update... anyway I just tried to move "webroot" from project.json to a new hosting.json, renamed to something else, visual studio restarted and move that dir to top and used it correctly...the same for the way back...may I try to ask if u ve latest vs2015 update?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest update (VS 2015 Update 1). The behavior you described doesn't occur if I follow that same process; adding a hosting.json file with the webroot value does not cause the renamed "wwwroot" directory (renamed to "test") to be used as the webroot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs don't quite explain your desired process. They assume someone wouldn't rename `wwwroot` but would just use another folder. As you mentioned in comments, you must use `hosting.json`, not `project.json` as was previously suggested. However, the order of operations matters if you want to rename `wwwroot` rather than just use another folder. To get the desired result:

1. Create the `test` folder (instead of renaming `wwwroot` folder)
2. Add the `hosting.json` file with the `webroot` entry pointing to the `test` folder.
3. If VS doesn't restart/reopen the project, just restart VS and you should see the `test` folder now show up as the `webroot`.

At that point, you can move contents from `wwwroot` to `test` if that hasn't already happened.

Comment: Works as advertised. :-) Marked as answer for extra clarity.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually rename the folder but you would need to update/create the **hosting.json** to specify the name of web root folder.

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot"
}
```

beware: there are changes in progress between releases that are not reflected in the [official docs](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.rst#the-wwwroot-folder) at the time of this post yet. i.e.: [check here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/450)

Comment: Webroot is ignored in the project.json file. It looks like a change was made and "webroot" has been removed from project.json and placed into hosting.json. https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/450

The thing is, even when I rename "wwwroot" folder to "test", and enter the value hosting.json file, VS regenerates the wwwroot folder and does not recognize the renamed folder as the web root folder.