# Changed asp.net core webroot and now cannot serve static files

Tags: asp.net-core

I changed my web root from the default wwwroot to "Public" by setting webroot in my project.json file and renaming the folder. Now none of my css or js files load in the browser. Is there something else I was supposed to do?

Comment: Refer this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110279/how-to-rename-wwwroot-folder-used-as-web-root-in-asp-net-5-web-project

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example!](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)